# github のプライベートレポジトリから一部のファイルのみをダウンロードするには？

Tags: git, github

github のプライベートレポジトリの、 master ブランチの `path/to/file` の場所にあるファイルないしディレクトリを（そしてそれだけを）手元にダウンロードしたくなりました。

これはどうやったら実現できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

普通の git サーバーならば、 `git archive --format=tar --remote=$git_url master path/to/file | tar -xf -` が使えるのですが、 github においてはこれが利用不可能です。

代わりに、`svn export` が利用できます。

```
$ GITHUB_TOKEN=abcdefgh...  # https://github.com/settings/tokens より生成
$ svn --username "${GITHUB_TOKEN}" --password '' export https://github.com/username/reponame/trunk/path/to/file export_dir
```

ポイントは

- `https://github.com/ユーザー名/プロジェクト名` が svn レポジトリとして利用可能
- 認証は、 github token を認証のユーザー名に指定することで突破可能

Answer (score 3):

特定のファイル・サブディレクトリのみを取得する方法はいくつかあり、バージョン依存します。

#### Git 2.19以降（2018/09リリース）

[`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)で`--filter`オプションが指定できます。

```
git clone --depth 1 --no-checkout --filter=blob:none $REPO workdir
cd workdir
git checkout master -- path/to/file
```

#### Git 1.7以降（2012/02リリース）

[sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresparseCheckout)が使えます。

```
mkdir workdir
cd workdir
git init
git remote add -f origin $REPO
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo path/to/file >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

---

[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/600079/4315484)を参考に書きました。`--depth 1`や`--no-checkout`、`--config`をうまく使えばsparse checkoutももう少し手際よく実現できるかも？

「github のプライベートレポジトリ」であることが質問にどのように影響するのかよくわかりませんでした。

Comment: github のレポジトリに対して `--filter` オプションを実行してみたところ、 `warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring` と表示されたので、 github.com では最初の選択肢は、(少なくとも今今は)利用不可能っぽいな、と思っています。